# Show/Hide not working on CSV loaded data

Tags: javascript, csv, show-hide

I have data loaded into a table from a csv file - this works perfectly though now I'm trying to get a show/hide feature working. There are hidden rows in the table and I want it to show the row below the one you click on. i wrote some code for it and preloaded the table with some data via the HTML and it workss fine - however as soon as I try and use it on the data which is laoded in using the CSV it won't work. PLEASE SOMEONE HELP ME!!!!

Comment: so we can help you, we need to see your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok I managed to resolve now  - it was running the script before the csv was laded - ty nayway Yule